# Problem with DHCP Server in Ubuntu Server

Tags: 10.10, server, dhcp

when I restart the DHCP server, these are the messages that I get from `syslog`

```
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd:
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd: No subnet declaration for eth0:138 (0.0.0.0).
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on eth0:138.  If this is not what
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd:    to which interface eth0:138 is attached. **
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd:
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd:
Feb 10 19:17:50 mustafa-sr1 dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
```

Comment: It would really help if you worded your question along with the output :)

Comment: This is likely a configuration issue, but it's impossible to be certain without seeing the configuration file. Please post the contents of `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to change the default configuration by editing `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf` to suit your needs and particular configuration.

[Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/dhcp.html)